# cancel touch event during touchesMoved

Tags: ios, uiview, touch, touch-event

I need to cancel a touch event during touchesMoved so that underlying uiviews can receive the events. See comments below:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    for (UITouch *touch in touches)
    {

        if (touch.view == self.touchOverlay) {
            CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

            //perform checks on touch location and trip sensor if circumstances are met

            if (self.touchSensorTripped) {
                self.touchOverlay.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
                //NEED TO CANCEL THE TOUCH HERE SO THAT VIEWS UNDERNEATH CAN RECEIVE THE TOUCH EVENTS
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Currently the underlying views do not receive touch events until the touch ENDS, which is too late. I need them to start receiving the touchesMoved events immediately once the overlay view is disabled, while the touches are still moving. What can I insert where the comment is above to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I just did some simple messing around with a test app, and found that calling 
`[[self superview]touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];` seemed to work for a straightforward view hierarchy, if that's what you have.  The superview's touchesMoved was definitely called before the view touchesEnded. Calling the superviews touchesMoved prematurely in this way didn't cause it to be called again afterwards

Comment: thanks for the response. Indeed I can get touchesMoved to be called in the parent view controller by calling self.superview touchesMoved. However, the underlying views contain scrollviews, and those scrollviews do not respond when touchesMoved is called manually. I need those scrollviews to work as normal. Can you think of any other way? I just wish the overlying view could pass the touches on the views beneath it.